# Outlook 2016 mapi.MAPIUninitialize() crashes

Tags: multithreading, ms-office, office365connectors

In my multi threaded application where multiple threads do mapiinitialize by

```
mapi.MAPIInitialize((0, mapi.MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS))

mapi.MAPIUninitialize() crashes. I got the following call stack from windbg.

mso30win32client!Ordinal250+0x32423    
mso30win32client!Ordinal126+0x5b   
mso30win32client!Ordinal1337+0x39d   
mso30win32client!Ordinal1470+0x17e    
mso30win32client!Ordinal1470+0xe    
mso40uiwin32client!Ordinal2408+0x19    
olmapi32!LINKEDLIST_RemoveKey+0x4e6   
olmapi32!HrUninitMso+0x36    
olmapi32!MAPIUninitialize+0x9    
MSMAPI32!MAPIUninitialize+0x42   
MAPI32!MAPIUninitialize+0x5b    
mapi+0x11d9
```

Each thread does only below mapi(Outlook 2016) calls in sequence :
1 MAPIInitialize
2 MAPIAdminProfiles
3 HrQueryAllRows
4 session=MAPILogonEx
5 session.logoff
6 MAPIUninitialize

Observation:
If there are two threads T1 and T2 .
T1 logs in to session prior to T2 and T1 does MAPIUninitialize after T2 it dont lead to crash,
But if T1 logs in to session prior to T2 and T1 does MAPIUninitialize before T2 then call to MAPIUninitialize leads to crash with above stack.

Crash is with Outlook 2016 only works fine with Outlook 2013 and prior.

Comment: I have similar bug but with Access OLEDB Engine (part of Office Access 2016), - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432816/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-bug-in-multithread-scenario
Try to update to Office latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Is T1 used on the main thread and T2 on a secondary?

Take a look at the [MAPI Multithreading Rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2004/09/24/mapi-multithreading-rules.aspx) page which states the following:

*If MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS is not used, the first thread to call MAPIInitialize should live longer than all other MAPI threads and should be the last to call MAPIUninitialize.*

Looks like the mentioned flag doesn't play any role now and you should preserve the sequence of calls, i.e. use LIFO (last in, first out).

Comment: Here T1 and T2 are threads at Sibling level,created by a thread say M.

Thread M do not do any mapi calls Hence I am not doing  mapi.MAPIInitialize  and mapi.MAPIUninitialize for thread M.

Is this could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call MAPIInitialize on the main thread before T1 and T2 start and call MAPIUninitialize after both threads exit.

Comment: Is it Mandatory to call MAPIInitialize and MAPIUninitialize on the main thread from Outlook 2016 as it works fine for Outlook 2013 and Prior.    
     
MAPIInitialize on the main thread before T1 and T2 start and MAPIUninitialize after both threads exits fails .

But if i call MAPIInitialize , MAPILogonEx  on the main thread before T1 and T2 start and Logoff and MAPIUninitialize after both threads exits It works fine      
      
Is there any relationship from main thread.

Comment: Yes. The first thread to call MAPIInitialize is considered by the MAPI system to be the main thread where things that have thread affinity (window handles etc.) are created. If what MAPI considers the main thread is killed while another thread is still using MAPI, bad things are bound to happen. This is not 2016 specific. You just got lucky before.

Comment: 1.MAPIInitialize on the main thread before T1 and T2 start and MAPIUninitialize for main thread after both threads exits also result to crash. Only if I call MAPIInitialize , MAPILogonEx on the main thread before T1 and T2 start and Logoff and MAPIUninitialize after both threads exits works fine


2.Even  If MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS flag is  pass  in  MAPIInitialize for the all the threads, first thread to call MAPIInitialize is considered by the MAPI system to be the main thread ?

Comment: There is need to handle multiple activities request by spawning thread for each activity.
Since there is no order in which each thread starts and exits Hence I am doing MAPIInitialize ,MAPILogonEx and Logoff ,MAPIUninitialize for each thread.
There is possibility that just one thread starts and do MAPIInitialize ,MAPILogonEx and Logoff ,MAPIUninitialize and exit
Or multiple threads starts do MAPIInitialize ,MAPILogonEx and Logoff ,MAPIUninitialize in parallel, each in its own context and exits in some random order.

Comment: IMAPISession can be shared among multiple threads. Call MAPIInitialize / MAPILogonEx on the main thread. Spawn secondary threads, on each thread call MAPIInitialize and use IMAPISession from the main thread.

Comment: What can be the possible reason for failure when multiple threads creates multiple session ?

Comment: I don't know. But creating a session on the main thread and sharing it with secondary threads works in all versions of Outlook.